# R - Telling me in which Row, the Value is not the Same in Row & Column

Tags: r

So I have a Table looking something like this.

```
         row col
X__11     1   1
X__12     2   2
X__13     3   3
X__14     4   4
X__15     5   5
X__16     6   7
X__17     7   6
```

I now want R to tell me in which X_... , the value in row is not equal to the value in the column.

Using the above Table as an example. I would like for R to tell me that in X_16 & X_17 the values are not equal

Comment: `with(tbl, row.names(tbl)[row != col])`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
y <- c(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6)
z <- c('x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 'x16')
df <- data.frame(z, x, y)
with(df, z[ifelse(x!=y, TRUE, NA)] )
```

This will print out:

```
[1] <NA> <NA> x13  x14  <NA> <NA>
```